# How to send a Node.js response(JSON) to a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, amcharts

I'm currently trying to plot data from MongoDB in a graph to display on a website.
What I have tried so far is getting the response from MongoDB using Node.js and mongoose, which returns a json object to the browser.

```
app.get('/pricediff',function(req,res){
    PriceDifference_collection.find({},{'_id':0},function(err,pricediff) {
        res.send(pricediff);
    })
});
```

I separately used amcharts to plot JSON objects using javascript.
But now I just pasted the JSON response I got from Node.js into the javascript file manually.

```
"dataProvider": {JSON data}
```

My question:
Is there a way to give the response from Node.js(JSON) directly to the javascript file?
Or are there more easy ways to plot data from my database? Maybe even use a complete different kind of database...

Comment: @Pogrindis Pretty sure this is just "bad english" for "send a JSON formatted response". So comment and answer were not really valid here.

Comment: @Pogrindis Wise man. Perhaps you should tell the other guy.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are running under "express" or a variant sub-classing this. Either way your basic line is either:

```
res.json({ "dataProvider": pricediff })
```

Or possibly:

```
res.send( JSON.stringify( { "dataProvider": pricediff }, undefined, 2 ) );
```

With the main difference being that the **first** option will automaticallt set the "Content-Type" header variable ( provided you haven't sent any response yet ) to the client as "application/json", which it should be.

Comment: I think its fair to say this question is slightly ambiguous, i suspected what you answered, but really couldnt be sure. I got another impression based on the fact he manually pasted JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to write your data to that js file

```
var fs=require('fs');
var resultObject=JSON.stringify({ "dataProvider": pricediff },undefined,2);
fs.writeFile('yourJsFile.js',resultObject, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```